# haven't provide instance field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception

Tags: java, junit4

class Example extends Parent{

```
public Example() {

    super(Example.class)
}
```

whenever I am trying the

public class Test{

```
@InjectMock Example example
@BeforeMethod
@BeforeTest
public void setUp(){

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

}
```

}

It is giving the above error mentioned.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the full complete error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

there are a pair of things in your code which not used correctly. I think there is a bit of confusion and is not clear enough what you what to do. I'll try to explain e give you something to read.

1. @Injectmocks annotation in Test class

The @Injectmocks annotation is used to create a real instance of a class in which you want to inject @Mock objects.
Take a look here for some examples:
https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/mockito-mock-injectmocks/ ,
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations

The annotation is an instance field annotation. This means that you cannot use that as you are doing on a method declaration, but you need to use that instead on a field into the test class.

Let's suppose you want to test a method in a class, then you will use this annotation to create an instance of that class which contains the method to be tested. Roughly speaking with analogies, injectmock is like the Spring @Autowire annotation, although not the same.

I've noticed now that probably this is what you where trying to do (the puplished code of the test class has not been highlighetd correctly). You should put new line after @InjectMock Example example. In any case, I think there is a mistake in how you use the super keyword.

2. Call to super constructor in Example constructor.

I don't know what is the constructor in Parent class and how is done, but the rule is you pass arguments of the Parent construtor in super keyword. So for exampe, if this is your parent constructor:

```
public Parent(String name){
this.name = name}
```

then you need to do this in Example:

```
public Example(String name, String code) {
    this.code = code;
    super(name);
}
```

You are passing a .class in super(), not a field.

I would like to give you more help. I suggest you to post your code more clearly and with complete classes.